# Is there a market for 1:1 teacher:learner interactive platform for coding?

Tags: source-code, research

I see a lot of new coders following general guides and courses but many of them often need to ask communities about parts that are not clear to them.

I am thinking about building a platform that would enable live courses (1:1 teacher:learner) with shared interactive code editor and voice chat.

Is there a market for such platform? Would it be interesting for teachers to provide such live courses (paid or free) and for learners to use such service?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi mauleros, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of resources kinda like that already exist;

[Rpl.it](https://repl.it/)

[CollabEdit](http://collabedit.com/)

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

[CodeBunk](https://codebunk.com/)

[CodeShare](https://codeshare.io/)

etc.

You'll have a hard time competing with most of these guys' infrastructure. Granted, none of these are really marketed as learning platforms specifically.